# C - Writing a custom handler

Tags: php, c

I've written a custom test method in PHP to give me a custom response when running simple tests. Is there a way to implement this in C without having to re-invent the wheel?

```
function test($assertion, $msg = null)
{
    assert_options(ASSERT_WARNING, false);

    if(assert($assertion))
    {
        echo "PASS: {$assertion}\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo $msg, "\n", "FAIL: {$assertion}\n";
    }
}
```

**My solution: (edit)**

```
void test(bool expected, bool actual)
{
    printf((expected == actual) ? "PASS" : "FAIL");
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure what you're asking here. If you just want a function to do a soft assert, it seems you already have that. What are you really looking for?

Comment: I apologize, I just came up with that solution a few minutes ago. Kind of dirty, but for running simple test(s), I thought this would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
void test(bool expected, bool actual, char *msg)
{
    printf(((expected == actual) ? "PASS: %s\n" : "FAIL: %s\n"), msg);
}
```

It has the same test-like characteristics and it outputs a simple message in the same format as your PHP function. Note that I have not tested this and I'm not sure if the ternary in the printf actually compiles, but my guess is that it does.

Comment: Shouldn't ```char* msg``` be ```const* char msg```? Is there a difference? And in this case, I'm assuming msg represents the failing message. I like what you've added. Nice.

Comment: If my programming hat's on right, you might have an extra brace, I think that's the only warning you would get.

Comment: The const really doesn't matter from the function's point of view. It might be smart to make it a const, just to ensure the message isn't modified, but the compiler shouldn't go crazy without it.